# can windows service enumerate desktop top level windows

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-services, enumerate

I'm trying to enumerate top level windows from a service coded in c++
I want to find a particular program which there are multi instances of it running but I want a particular one which have some unique words in its window title

so I'm using this code :

```
 auto desktop = OpenInputDesktop( 0, FALSE, DESKTOP_READOBJECTS);
 if (!desktop) log_file << "[*] OpenDesktopA failed with error : " << GetLastError() << endl;
BOOL rs = EnumDesktopWindows(desktop, EnumProc, 0);
if (!rs) log_file << "[*] EnumDesktopWindows failed with error : " << GetLastError() << endl;
```

the EnumDesktopWindows  fails without calling the EnumProc so GetLastError returns zero

the same code works in non sevice program

is it possible to do this in a service but I'm doing something wrong ?
or I can't achieve this ?

Comment: I believe this is a security feature of the OS before vista services could interact with the GUI.

Comment: I gave my service the permission to interact with the desktop and set the NoInteractiveServices in registry to 0

Comment: Interactive Services simply do not exist anymore as of Vista onwards, due to Session 0 Isolation.  A service can enumerate running processes easily enough, but GUI elements cannot be accessed across session boundaries. You are better off having the service spawn a separate worker process in the desired session and let that process enumerate the GUI windows as needed and communicate information about them back to the service via an IPC mechanism of your choosing

Comment: from here : [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c4d26cf3-9e73-48ef-9632-74ed964cff2e/using-enumwindows-in-a-vista-service?forum=vclanguage) someone said EnumDesktopWindows is the required function and the asker said it woked !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the final solution seems to make a helper process which will list the windows and find the id of the required windows the send it to the service through pipes or sockets or other communication techniques

Answer (score -1):

found one of the problems above , it was the access right 
I should use this access instead :

```
auto desktop = OpenInputDesktop(0, 0, GENERIC_ALL); // GENERIC_READ also enough
EnumDesktopWindows(desktop, EnumProc, 0);
```

however I got only two windows : HPSISVC , Default IME
while running this code in an ordinary program prints all the windows titles

Comment: This should be a comment to your question as it is not a real answer. You could also edit your question to include this as what you have tried.